# rake assets:precompile After changing ruby version and bundler version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, assets, precompile

After upgrading the ruby version and the bundler version to my app I got error when pushing my app to heroku

My ruby version is ruby '2.4.0'
My bundle is 2.0.2

I tried to find answer in stack overflow but without any luck! Can some one help me to fix it 
Precompiling assets failed.
Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.

```
$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 51, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (39/39), done.
Writing objects: 100% (42/42), 4.98 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 42 (delta 27), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.4.0
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.15.2
remote:        Purging Cache. Changing stack from cedar-14 to heroku-18
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        Your Gemfile lists the gem byebug (>= 0) more than once.
remote:        You should probably keep only one of them.
remote:        While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of one of them later.
remote:        The git source `git://github.com/amro/gibbon.git` uses the `git` protocol, which transmits data without encryption. Disable this warning with `bundle config git.allow_insecure true`, or switch to the `https` protocol to keep your data secure.
remote:        Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.15.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.17.3). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
remote:        Fetching git://github.com/amro/gibbon.git
remote:        Fetching rake 12.3.3
remote:        Fetching concurrent-ruby 1.1.5
remote:        Fetching json 1.8.6
remote:        Installing rake 12.3.3
remote:        Installing json 1.8.6 with native extensions
remote:        Installing concurrent-ruby 1.1.5
remote:        Fetching minitest 5.11.3
remote:        Installing minitest 5.11.3
remote:        Fetching thread_safe 0.3.6
remote:        Installing thread_safe 0.3.6
remote:        Fetching builder 3.2.3
remote:        Fetching erubis 2.7.0
remote:        Installing builder 3.2.3
remote:        Installing erubis 2.7.0
remote:        Fetching mini_portile2 2.4.0
remote:        Installing mini_portile2 2.4.0
remote:        Fetching crass 1.0.4
remote:        Installing crass 1.0.4
remote:        Fetching rack 1.6.11
remote:        Installing rack 1.6.11
remote:        Fetching mini_mime 1.0.2
remote:        Installing mini_mime 1.0.2
remote:        Fetching arel 6.0.4
remote:        Installing arel 6.0.4
remote:        Fetching bcrypt 3.1.13
remote:        Fetching rb-fsevent 0.10.3
remote:        Installing rb-fsevent 0.10.3
remote:        Installing bcrypt 3.1.13 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching ffi 1.11.1
remote:        Installing ffi 1.11.1 with native extensions
remote:        Using bundler 1.15.2
remote:        Fetching rubyzip 1.2.3
remote:        Installing rubyzip 1.2.3
remote:        Fetching tilt 2.0.9
remote:        Installing tilt 2.0.9
remote:        Fetching climate_control 0.2.0
remote:        Installing climate_control 0.2.0
remote:        Fetching coffee-script-source 1.12.2
remote:        Installing coffee-script-source 1.12.2
remote:        Fetching execjs 2.7.0
remote:        Installing execjs 2.7.0
remote:        Fetching thor 0.20.3
remote:        Installing thor 0.20.3
remote:        Fetching orm_adapter 0.5.0
remote:        Installing orm_adapter 0.5.0
remote:        Fetching multipart-post 2.1.1
remote:        Installing multipart-post 2.1.1
remote:        Fetching multi_json 1.13.1
remote:        Installing multi_json 1.13.1
remote:        Fetching mime-types-data 3.2019.0331
remote:        Installing mime-types-data 3.2019.0331
remote:        Fetching mimemagic 0.3.0
remote:        Installing mimemagic 0.3.0
remote:        Fetching pdf-core 0.2.5
remote:        Installing pdf-core 0.2.5
remote:        Fetching pg 0.21.0
remote:        Installing pg 0.21.0 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching ttfunk 1.2.2
remote:        Installing ttfunk 1.2.2
remote:        Fetching prawn-table 0.1.2
remote:        Installing prawn-table 0.1.2
remote:        Fetching rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.5
remote:        Installing rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.5
remote:        Fetching rails_stdout_logging 0.0.5
remote:        Installing rails_stdout_logging 0.0.5
remote:        Fetching rdoc 4.3.0
remote:        Installing rdoc 4.3.0
remote:        Fetching turbolinks-source 5.2.0
remote:        Installing turbolinks-source 5.2.0
remote:        Fetching i18n 0.9.5
remote:        Installing i18n 0.9.5
remote:        Fetching tzinfo 1.2.5
remote:        Installing tzinfo 1.2.5
remote:        Fetching nokogiri 1.10.4
remote:        Installing nokogiri 1.10.4 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching mail 2.7.1
remote:        Installing mail 2.7.1
remote:        Fetching rack-test 0.6.3
remote:        Installing rack-test 0.6.3
remote:        Fetching warden 1.2.7
remote:        Installing warden 1.2.7
remote:        Fetching sprockets 3.7.2
remote:        Fetching cocaine 0.5.8
remote:        Installing cocaine 0.5.8
remote:        Installing sprockets 3.7.2
remote:        Fetching coffee-script 2.4.1
remote:        Installing coffee-script 2.4.1
remote:        Fetching uglifier 4.1.20
remote:        Installing uglifier 4.1.20
remote:        Fetching faraday 0.15.4
remote:        Installing faraday 0.15.4
remote:        Fetching mime-types 3.2.2
remote:        Fetching rb-inotify 0.10.0
remote:        Installing rb-inotify 0.10.0
remote:        Installing mime-types 3.2.2
remote:        Fetching prawn 1.2.1
remote:        Fetching rails_12factor 0.0.3
remote:        Installing rails_12factor 0.0.3
remote:        Fetching turbolinks 5.2.0
remote:        Installing turbolinks 5.2.0
remote:        Installing prawn 1.2.1
remote:        Fetching activesupport 4.2.5
remote:        Installing activesupport 4.2.5
remote:        Fetching sdoc 0.4.2
remote:        Installing sdoc 0.4.2
remote:        Using gibbon 3.2.1 from git://github.com/amro/gibbon.git (at master@4f0d2d2)
remote:        Fetching sass-listen 4.0.0
remote:        Installing sass-listen 4.0.0
remote:        Fetching rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
remote:        Installing rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
remote:        Fetching globalid 0.4.2
remote:        Installing globalid 0.4.2
remote:        Fetching activemodel 4.2.5
remote:        Installing activemodel 4.2.5
remote:        Fetching jbuilder 2.9.1
remote:        Installing jbuilder 2.9.1
remote:        Fetching sass 3.7.4
remote:        Installing sass 3.7.4
remote:        Fetching activejob 4.2.5
remote:        Installing activejob 4.2.5
remote:        Fetching activerecord 4.2.5
remote:        Installing activerecord 4.2.5
remote:        Fetching paperclip 4.3.7
remote:        Installing paperclip 4.3.7
remote:        Fetching bootstrap-sass 3.2.0.4
remote:        Installing bootstrap-sass 3.2.0.4
remote:        Fetching friendly_id 5.2.5
remote:        Installing friendly_id 5.2.5
remote:        Fetching rails-dom-testing 1.0.9
remote:        Fetching loofah 2.2.3
remote:        Fetching aws-sdk-v1 1.67.0
remote:        Installing rails-dom-testing 1.0.9
remote:        Installing loofah 2.2.3
remote:        Fetching caracal 1.4.1
remote:        Installing caracal 1.4.1
remote:        Fetching rails-html-sanitizer 1.2.0
remote:        Installing rails-html-sanitizer 1.2.0
remote:        Fetching actionview 4.2.5
remote:        Installing aws-sdk-v1 1.67.0
remote:        Installing actionview 4.2.5
remote:        Fetching actionpack 4.2.5
remote:        Fetching aws-sdk 1.67.0
remote:        Installing actionpack 4.2.5
remote:        Installing aws-sdk 1.67.0
remote:        Fetching railties 4.2.5
remote:        Fetching htmltoword 0.5.1
remote:        Fetching actionmailer 4.2.5
remote:        Installing actionmailer 4.2.5
remote:        Fetching sprockets-rails 3.2.1
remote:        Installing sprockets-rails 3.2.1
remote:        Installing htmltoword 0.5.1
remote:        Installing railties 4.2.5
remote:        Fetching coffee-rails 4.1.1
remote:        Fetching responders 2.4.1
remote:        Fetching jquery-rails 4.3.5
remote:        Installing coffee-rails 4.1.1
remote:        Installing responders 2.4.1
remote:        Fetching jquery-ui-rails 6.0.1
remote:        Fetching rails 4.2.5
remote:        Installing jquery-ui-rails 6.0.1
remote:        Installing jquery-rails 4.3.5
remote:        Fetching sass-rails 5.0.7
remote:        Installing sass-rails 5.0.7
remote:        Fetching devise 4.7.0
remote:        Installing devise 4.7.0
remote:        Installing rails 4.2.5
remote:        Bundle complete! 28 Gemfile dependencies, 84 gems now installed.
remote:        Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
remote:        Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
remote:        Post-install message from sass:
remote:        
remote:        Ruby Sass has reached end-of-life and should no longer be used.
remote:        
remote:        * If you use Sass as a command-line tool, we recommend using Dart Sass, the new
remote:          primary implementation: https://sass-lang.com/install
remote:        
remote:        * If you use Sass as a plug-in for a Ruby web framework, we recommend using the
remote:          sassc gem: https://github.com/sass/sassc-ruby#readme
remote:        
remote:        * For more details, please refer to the Sass blog:
remote:          https://sass-lang.com/blog/posts/7828841
remote:        
remote:        Post-install message from prawn:
remote:        
remote:          ********************************************
remote:        
remote:        
remote:          A lot has changed recently in Prawn.
remote:        
remote:          Please read the changelog for details:
remote:        
remote:          https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn/wiki/CHANGELOG
remote:        
remote:        
remote:          ********************************************
remote:        
remote:        Bundle completed (45.90s)
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote:        Your Gemfile lists the gem byebug (>= 0) more than once.
remote:        You should probably keep only one of them.
remote:        While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of one of them later.
remote:        The git source `git://github.com/amro/gibbon.git` uses the `git` protocol, which transmits data without encryption. Disable this warning with `bundle config git.allow_insecure true`, or switch to the `https` protocol to keep your data secure.
remote:        Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.15.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.17.3). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
remote: -----> Installing node-v10.15.3-linux-x64
remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        /tmp/build_d122043ebb9c4179017606a51e6024c3/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
remote:        /tmp/build_d122043ebb9c4179017606a51e6024c3/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        SystemStackError: stack level too deep
remote:        /tmp/build_d122043ebb9c4179017606a51e6024c3/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:125:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
remote:        /tmp/build_d122043ebb9c4179017606a51e6024c3/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
remote:        /tmp/build_d122043ebb9c4179017606a51e6024c3/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
remote:        /tmp/build_d122043ebb9c4179017606a51e6024c3/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
remote:        /tmp/build_d122043ebb9c4179017606a51e6024c3/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
remote:        /tmp/build_d122043ebb9c4179017606a51e6024c3/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
remote:        /tmp/build_d122043ebb9c4179017606a51e6024c3/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
remote:        /tmp/build_d122043ebb9c4179017606a51e6024c3/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i met an error before, i solved that i will update `rails version` to `4.2.10`.
It seem that you used rails `4.2.5`.

In my case, i only do as:
In `Gemfile`, i put as `gem 'rails', '~> 4.2.10'`

Then run `bundle update rails`.

And everything solved. Hope that my case can help to solve your problem.

Comment: Where it tell to update the rails version? How do you figure it out?